# C Program for modifying linked list causes segmentation fault even though memory is allocated

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

For my program, I have to start with an empty linked list, and be able to perform various operations on it (i.e. add to beginning, add to end etc.) 
My list structure is as follows

```
struct node {
int num;
struct node *next;
};
```

This is the beginning of the function where I have allocated the space and initialized the list, followed by a while loop, where case 1 is the add to beginning function. The else part can be disregarded for this problem.

```
printf("Who's ready to create and edit a linked list?\n");
printf("Note: The list is currently empty, please choose option 1.\n");
int choice, val, location, created;
struct node *llist;
llist = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
created =0;
while(choice != 8)
  {
    printf("      Operation Choices\n");
    printf("1. Insert node at beginning\n");
    printf("2. Insert node at end\n");
    printf("3. Delete node from end\n");
    printf("4. Delete node from beginning\n");
    printf("5. Delete node from custom position\n");
    printf("6. Insert node at custom position\n");
    printf("7. Modify custom node\n");
    printf("8. Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice) {
    case 1:
      printf("Value to enter: \n");
      scanf("%d", val);
      if(created == 0)
      {
        llist->num=val;
        llist->next = NULL;
        created = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        struct node *temp;
        temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp = llist;
        free(llist);
        llist = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        llist->num=val;
        llist->next=temp;
        free(temp);
        showlist(llist);
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

}

Choice is currently at '0', which indicates I have not added any values to the list and the if section is being executed. When I run the code and attempt to add my first value, I keep getting a segmentation fault, even though memory is allocated. What am I missing??

Any idea why this print function is not working either?

```
void showlist(struct node *list)
{
 do{
   printf("%d->", list->num);
   list = list->next;
 }
 while(list->next != NULL);
}
```

Comment: `temp = llist;
        free(llist);` why?

Comment: Temp contains the whole list, so I thought I should free the memory to make the new first node. Without the free(llist), it still produces a segmentation fault.

Comment: @ebagl temp does not contain the whole list, temp contains the address of the first node in the list. Then `free(llist)` frees the first node in the list.

Comment: `temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); temp = llist;` This is a memory leak. You `malloc` space for `temp`, then reassign `temp` to a different value without saving its original value. That memory is now dangling with no references to it.

Comment: So should no memory be allocated for 'temp'  then? I have also tried that with no success.

Comment: no, if you want to create a node you have to allocate memory for it, you just need to keep a reference, some how, to all of the memory you allocate. This code is pretty far removed from how a linked list should work. It would be helpful to google for some tutorials and to draw the operations of inserting, removing, etc out on paper to make sure you understand how they work before writing any code. I know youtube has some linked list tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

For starters:

```
scanf("%d", val);
```

That will store the value the user types into *address* specified by `val`, which is undefined at this point.  You want to store it in the address *of* `val`.

Should be:

```
scanf("%d", &val);
```

And your "else" clause needs a lot of work.  It can be reduced to this:

```
  else
  {
    struct node *insertnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    insertnode->num = val;
    insertnode->next = llist;
    llist = insertnode;
  }
```

Now let's clean up your entire function.

First step. Just leave the `llist` initialized to NULL when your program starts and get rid of the `created` variable.

```
struct node *llist = NULL;
```

Then your `case 1`, which is to create a new node and insert it at the head is simply this:

```
case 1:
{
    /* create a new node and make it the new head of the list */
    struct node* insertnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Value to enter: \n");
    scanf("%d", &(insertnode->val));
    insertnode->next = llist; /* next points to the existing head, which will be null on first call */
    llist = insertnode; /* head now points to the new node*/

    break;
}
```

Comment: +1 for that, Very tired right now. The else section of the function now does not work, are you able to see what the issue is there?

Comment: I didn't know you were answering so I added your answer as reference for the problem of `scanf` which you discussed at that time. Now it seems you edited your whole answer.

Comment: I would say my answer evolved as a result of continuous integration.

Comment: This shows me the flaws in my way, great fix. Thank you for helping the obviously new coder.

Comment: If you find the answer useful, don't forget to upvote it and/or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `scanf()` you need to put `&val` instead of `val`.

For the else part, why are you releasing the memory of `llist`? Instead of checking the created variable you can directly check whether the list is `null` or not.
And I will suggest to use a `Head` node in this case. Then you can easily assign the `next` of the current node to point to the previously added node and assign the `next` of the head node to the currently added node.

Comment: After I assign the `head->` to the next element, would my list not then start with the struct `head` as opposed to `llist`?

Comment: Don't assign `head` to the next element. Do something like this :
`head->next = *CurrentlyAddedNode`

Then call the `head` node to display

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems. Apart from what selbie (First edit) said there are few others:-

1. There is a problem with your understanding of how things work out. For example you have written

   ```
   temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   temp = llist;
   ```

   This is a memory leak. And why is this needed? Because you wanted to add a new node. But you didn't use it properly.
2. The design of the code is not that good I would say- - `llist` allocated memory outside the loop and it is modified inside of it. Why not allocate the memory where it is needed? You can change that.
3. So you can modify it to this:-(This adds new nodes to the head of the list)

   ```
     if(created == 0)
     {
       llist = malloc(sizeof *llist);
       llist->num=val;
       llist->next = NULL;
       created = 1;
     }
     else
     {
       struct node *temp;
       temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
       temp->num=val;
       temp->next=llist;
       llist = temp;
       showlist(llist);
     }
   ```

   Those casting for `malloc` is not needed. And for sure you can check the return value of `malloc`. Free these memories when you are done working with the whole list.
4. Simply put `showList` function would be something like

   ```
   void showlist(struct node *list) {
       while(list)
       { 
           printf("%d->", list->num); 
           list = list->next; 
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: @ebagl.: Check .

Comment: That print function produces a segmentation fault... I am lost

Comment: @ebagl.: You have modified the code as per my suggestion? For both the modification?

Comment: @ebagl.: Good job. Answer helped?

Comment: @ebagl Since coderredoc helped you it is a good manner to Up vote the answer and/or accept it.